# Not able to run some .exe files via SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour while trying to run some .exe file on EC2 instance via SSM. When i try to run it trough SSM console, nothing happens as it's not started and i'm not getting any output in form of error or a warning.

I tried running file both with basic command ".\FileName.exe" and with Start-Process and got same result. Start-Process would return that it had started some process with some ID, but when i do Get-Process right after it says that it doesn't exist.
I also checked the logs located on %PROGRAMDATA%\Amazon\SSM\Logs\ but no information there either. I checked permissions and I'm pretty sure that it's not the reason cause i'm able to run some other files in same manner. But when I did RDP to that machine and tried to run that file trough powershell or cmd and it runs without any problems.

It's really confusing cause i'm not getting any information that can help me locate the issue.

Anyone experienced similar issue?

Comment: What kind of application is this? Is it a command-line only application or does the application provide a graphical user interface?

Comment: That exe file is command line application.